# Link_to a specific product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

New to Rails and trying to figure out how to set-up a `link_to` that goes to a `user`'s specific `property`.  So in my case, `property` `belongs_to` `user` and `user` `has_many` `properties`.  I'm using Devise and CanCan. Just need for the current `user` to be redirected to their `property`.

Issue right now is that it tries to redirect to the same `property_id` as the `user_id`. (e.g. user/15 gets attempts to redirect to 'property/15' even though when I check the console - let's say the user's property is property/18 - it has a `user_id` of 15 - so there is an association created that's correct) Just can't figure out how to get the `link_to` to go to property 18 (example) and not 15.

Appreciate any help!

Users/show

```
 <div class="col-mds-6">
          <%= link_to "View Property", property_path(@user), :class      => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom" %>
  </div>
```

Controller/Users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


before_action :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Route:

```
resources :properties, :users, :orders, :charges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `current user` to be redirected to their `property`

You'd need to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/properties_controller.rb
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user.properties.find params[:id]
  end
end

#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% @user.properties.each do |property| %>
  <%= link_to property.name, property %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  I tried this before and again now but I get an error message `Couldn't find Property with 'id'=15 [WHERE "properties"."user_id" = ?]` in the controller.

Comment: Ended up chaing the `property.name` to `property.user_id` and it worked.  Far easier than the other solution where everything was nested.  Thanks!

Comment: You'd need it to be nested if you wanted to show a `user`'s properties. Since you only wanted to show properties for `current_user` the above should suffice. Glad it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your link having `property_path(@user)` where `@user` is an instance of `User` not `Property`. That is why the `:id` in the route has user's id(**15**), not property's(**18**)

Use [**nested resources**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

```
resources :users do
  resources :properties
end

#users/show.html.erb

<% @user.properties.each do | property | %>
  <%= link_to "View Property", user_property_path(@user, property), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked.  I was hesitant to nest the `property` in the `user` because I still need the ability for a property to be viewed by users that are not logged in.  I think if I understand Rails now, this is still possible - correct? Do I just send a redirect in routes to do this?

Comment: Think I figured it out.  I've moved the `properties` `index` route outside of the nesting in my routes file so it's accessible without a user.  I'm having problems though with setting a `link_to` to the properties/show page from the index page.  Because it's outside of the nesting and the show page is inside the nesting, I have to change my current `link_to` on the page but can't figure out how to get it to work.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
resources :users do
  resources :properties
end
```

User/show

```
<div class="col-mds-6">
  <%= link_to "View Property", user_property_path(@user, property), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom" %>
</div>
```

Controller

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Here, you can't get the `:property_id` as the relation is different.